# Compare Regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Let's assume we have two regex pattern, which are different but actually mean the same, e.g.:

```
XX[0-9]{1,5}:.*

XX[0-9]{1,5}: .*
```

Only difference is the space previous to the .* Is there a way to check if these pattern get the same matches?

Comment: The first would match "XX00000:ABC" but the second wouldn't because there isn't a space.  I'm not sure if that's what you are asking or if you want a way to find differences between two regular expressions.

Comment: The first would match `XX0:` but not the second...

Comment: I just need a bool if these would get the same matches, is there a way?

Comment: like the answer from @dotNET says, yes, but not easily. Sorry!

Comment: That's a significantly hard problem to solve unless you limit it to a specific set of data.  Why do you need to check if two regular expressions get the same results?

Comment: See answer to  [Algorithm to determine whether two regexes are equivalent] (http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12267/algorithm-to-determine-whether-two-regexes-are-equivalent)

Answer (score 2):

There are infinitely many ways of writing a regex that would effectively match the same set of strings.

**Example**

The following 3 regex match the same set of strings. This can be expanded arbitrarily.

```
[A-Z]{3}
[A-Z][A-Z]{2}    
[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]
```

**Update**

I did some more research and found a [paper](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/henglein/papers/ginzburg1967.pdf) that describes how such a procedure can be implemented. I couldn't find any ready-to-use sample though.

Comment: *This is not possible* - can you prove that? "There are infinitely many ways of writing a regex that would effectively match the same set of strings" does not necessarily imply "You can't write a tool to check if two regular expressions would match the same set of strings".

Comment: @Rawling: Agree with u here. Although I couldn't come up with any code example, there is a [paper](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/henglein/papers/ginzburg1967.pdf) that promises that such a procedure can be implemented. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The two regex's in your example don't actually mean the same thing.

You can check the matches for a regex easily online using http://regexhero.net/tester/. The pro version's analyse functionality might help in comparing regex's manually.

If you have a limited subset of testdata, you could write a test harness that checks all of that data and shows inconsistencies. Otherwise, perhaps there is technically a way to prove that they give the same results, but it's too complicated for just throwing together a simple program to do it.

If you explain why you need this, perhaps we can help some more